# PL/SQL Throwing Error ORA-02289: sequence does not exist (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I created a table using `SQL Developer`. In my table the ID column, I made it to be an auto incremental numeric column. When I get the SQL for the table from SQL tab in the `SQL Developer` and try to run the it in another instance of the DB, I get an exception:

[image: SQL Developer Error Message]

I am trying to run the script:

```
CREATE TABLE "GAL_ABS_DB"."DEVICE_LOCKING" 
(   "ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
"TECH" VARCHAR2(6 BYTE), 
"DEVICENAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
"LOCKINGTYPE" VARCHAR2(16 BYTE), 
"LOCKINGDEFINITION" VARCHAR2(6 BYTE)
) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "GAL_ABS_DB" ;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "GAL_ABS_DB"."DEVICE_LOCKING_TRIGGER" 
BEFORE INSERT ON DEVICE_LOCKING 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  <<COLUMN_SEQUENCES>>
  BEGIN
    IF INSERTING AND :NEW.ID IS NULL THEN
      SELECT DEVICE_LOCKING_SEQ.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM SYS.DUAL;
    END IF;
  END COLUMN_SEQUENCES;
END;
/
ALTER TRIGGER "GAL_ABS_DB"."DEVICE_LOCKING_TRIGGER" ENABLE;
```

Can you please tell me what this is complaining about? I got the script from SQL Developer itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably the DEVICE_LOCKING_SEQ sequence object does not exist.

This would be a standalone object in its own right and not, for example, part of a table. So you should have a CREATE SEQUENCE ... statement

Comment: So just adding the statement: `CREATE SEQUENCE DEVICE_LOCKING_SEQ;` at the beginning should do it?

Comment: _"So just adding the statement: CREATE SEQUENCE DEVICE_LOCKING_SEQ; at the beginning should do it?"_   Why not just try it and see?

Comment: Probably best if you look up the correct syntax for creating sequences and then go from there

Comment: possibles causes could be : the sequence does not exists or you have not the required privilege to perform this operation.Make sure the sequence name is correct, and that you have the right to perform the desired operation on this sequence

Comment: @hell_storm2004 Yes, `create sequence device_locking_seq;` is probably fine. You could increase the cache size if it's going to be really high volume, and check the other options in [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-SEQUENCE.html) if there's anything nonstandard about it (multiple RAC instances etc) but `create sequence sequencename` is nearly always fine.

Answer (score 1):

Generated code is usually hideous. I would just create the table as:

```
create table device_locking 
( id                 integer generated always as identity
, tech               varchar2(6)
, devicename         varchar2(20)
, lockingtype        varchar2(16)
, lockingdefinition  varchar2(6) );
```

Most of the storage settings are the defaults anyway, except `SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE` - do you really want that? The `FLASH_CACHE` details are only for Exadata.

If you want the old-school named sequence and maybe a PK, you could use

```
create sequence device_locking_seq;

create table device_locking 
( id                 integer
                     default on null device_locking_seq.nextval
                     constraint device_locking_pk primary key
, tech               varchar2(6)
, devicename         varchar2(20)
, lockingtype        varchar2(16)
, lockingdefinition  varchar2(6) );
```

Comment: I am not that much of a DB expert to know. I only know the basic, Select, Inset, Update, Delete commands to get by day-to-day. That is why rely on SQL Developer's GUI to create tables and it auto-generated script to add tables to other DB instances. Last time i did PL/SQL, was in the mid 2000s, so needless to say, don't remember much. I got mine to work adding a sequence before the table. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: I wish i could select two answers! But since Nick's came before, I had to select it!  :(

Comment: No worries. Glad it helped.